# How to push update to user without multiple updates if more than one tab is open?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

When a function is run, an update gets pushed to the user,
but if the user has 2 or more tabs open, it'll update equal to the number of tabs open.

I'd like the update to only apply once per user regardless of how many connections have have to the server.

any ideas on how to stop/fix this?

Comment: maybe a sample of your code will provide a better understanding of your problem.

Comment: You'll have to provide the server with some sort of information unique to each computer, and then filter requests on the server side based on that information. For example, you could ascertain the IP address of each user, and when you broadcast a message, not send that message to users with the same IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to sharing a connection in the browser side. With this support, regardless of the number of tabs, a physical connection will be established once per device and notifications from the server will be broadcasted to the tabs. So, the server don't need to consider that.

In fact, I added this support to my library, [the portal](https://github.com/flowersinthesand/portal), but there were [some arguments](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/socket_io/7lwKJqyNrvk/indTVDqmqyIJ). If you want to implement or enhance the connection sharing from scratch, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554896/sharing-websocket-across-browser-tabs/11458341#11458341) to a similar question. However, that is somewhat out of date.